# grep through and return contents of href if it matches?

Tags: linux, grep

Here is my current grep:

```
grep -l -R "battle/" * > /home/results.txt
(This returns the files that it is in)
```

I want to look through every file and find the instance "battle/" and then compile a list of what link it is pointing to.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/battle/index.php">Index</a>
<a href="http://www.site.com/battle/contact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="http://www.site.com/battle/go/here/folder/file.php">Long weird path</a>
```

And I want the grep results to return like so:

```
http://www.site.com/battle/index.php
http://www.site.com/battle/contact.php
http://www.site.com/battle/go/here/folder/file.php
```

Basically, we have links to pages inside a folder we are deleting, so we want to find what links are still being used in these pages.

I want to earch for battle/ and return the whole path inside the href.

I then want the results to output to my results.txt file.

How would I go about doing this grep? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky to do this 100% reliably, with zero risk of missing something you want or catching something you don't; but a good first approximation might be:

```
grep -R -o 'http://www.site.com/battle/[^"]*' * > /home/results.txt
```

(The `-o` flag says to "only" output the actual matched strings, rather than the entire lines containing them.)

Needless to say, this won't catch any links using relative URLs, like `<a href="/battle/contact.php">` or whatnot, and it will get confused if a link wraps the URL in single-quotes instead of double-quotes . . . and there are various other ways it can go wrong. `grep` is basically limited by your confidence in the exact shape of your input data. When the input data weren't initially created with `grep` in mind, it can be hard to achieve perfect confidence.

Comment: Good one. +1 I'd probably add the `href=" ... "` to get something like `'href="[^"]*/battle/[^"]*"` and then `| sed` to remove the href and quotes which could catch relative URLs. And depending on how picky I wanted to be.